# Temporary storage for files

Tags: .net, database, architecture, nosql, data-storage

I need to store files during 30 minutes (or less), then I need to delete it (after processing or by timer).

Non-functional requirements

It must be free and it is desirable to  have .net adapter.

loading:

First milestone: 10-20 new files per minute.

Second milestone: 100-200 new files per minute.

Third milestone: 1000-3000 new files per minute.

File size: <10mb - 90%, >10mb - 10%.

I need two solutions: hard storage (file system or db) and memory storage.

What do you advice me?

PS: currently, I research MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem.

If you do some maths first and look at the max you will need to support:

3000 files per min is 50 per sec **on average**, if we assume an average file size of 5 MB, that is 250 MB. Then all files will not come at the average speed, so you will need to support atleast 1 GB per second.

At that speed just pushing it across the network becomes a problem.

You therefore need to spread your data across many database servers and network segments.

This spliting of databases is called sharding, MongoDB supports sharding. For others see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application on one server you can use isolated storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=VS.100).aspx